# What is an alternative for Lucene Query's extractTerms?

Tags: lucene, query-parser

In Lucene 4.6.0 there was the method extractTerms that provided the extraction of terms from a query ([Query 4.6.0](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html?is-external=true)). However, from Lucene 6.2.1, it does no longer exist ([Query Lucene 6.2.1](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html?is-external=true)). Is there a valid alternative for it?

What I'd need is to parse terms (and corrispondent fields) of a Query built by QueryParser.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: I need to compute tfidf of each term in the query, so I need to iterate over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best answer but one way is to use the same analyzer and tokenize the query string:

```
Analyzer anal = new StandardAnalyzer();
TokenStream ts = anal.tokenStream("title", query); // string query
CharTermAttribute termAtt = ts.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
ts.reset();
while (ts.incrementToken()) {
    System.out.println(termAtt.toString());
}
anal.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have temporarely solved my problem with the following code. Smarter alternatives will be well accepted:

```
QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("title", a);
Query q = qp.parse(query);
Set<Term> termQuerySet = new HashSet<Term>();
Weight w = searcher.createWeight(q, true, 3.4f);
w.extractTerms(termQuerySet);
```